# Silverlight and local singleton

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible for multiple instances of a Silverlight application running on the same local computer to get a hold of a local object instance on that compputer.

I'm thinking about having a WCF service hosted as a window service on the local computer which hands the Silverlight applications the singleton object to use.  But I am not sure if it's a good solution or possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good. If you don't want to do all sorts of hacks in silverlight calling COM objects your idea is the right way to go.